# Share the internet of one WiFi card through a hotspot of another WiFi card

Tags: networking, wifi, routing, networkmanager, access-point

I have two WiFi cards. One is connected to a router, and gets an internet connection. The other is set up as an Access Point (AP), to which devices are able to connect. But they don't get any internet. How to share the internet from WiFi-1 (`wlan1`) over to WiFi-2 (`wlan2`)?

I'm using Fedora KDE.

---

After adding a bridge between the two, using the GUI:

Settings in `Connection - System settings` - I assume this is NetworkManager settings. I am able to connect to the AP with my android phone, but only if I specify IP,Gateway, Prefix Length and DNS by hand. I have tried to mimick the configuration of the host computer with the AP; using the same IP and gateway, and also use the same IP but incremented by 1. Either way, the phone is able to connect but does not get internet.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: there are multiple tutorial, I used this one for my Pi https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

Comment: @Archemar that tutorial doesn't translate well to Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

You can go about this multiple ways: If you want to integrate the Wifi to which you're into your other network, you'd go into the graphical network manager and add a new *bridge* connection (`nm-connection-editor`, then click on plus), to which you assign both network devices.

If you want these two networks to be separate, but able to exchange packets, you'd configure *routing* between these. This is relatively easy:

You'd want to configure the DHCP server that hands out addresses (or radius if that is what the AP uses to authenticate users) to tell clients on the "internal" wifi that your computer is the default route.

On your machine, you just `ip route add aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/24 dev wlan2` (assuming that is your Wifi's netmask) and `ip route add www.xxx.yyy.zzz/24 dev wlan2` so that your computer knows where to put packets, and enable IPv4 forwarding between the two of these.

Comment: Can you guide me though the graphical approach? There's a lot to be said there. I assume that I start out with `Add > WiFi` for both devices. Then? What mode should I use for the AP card? The AP is configured as `AP`, naturally, but when adding the device to the bridge, I have to choose once more. Should the IPv4 mode of the bridge be `Automatic`, or `Shared to other computers`, like the AP?

Comment: One more thing: When creating the AP, I chose `Shared to other computers` for the IPv4 mode. But my Android phone is not able to get an IP, is just connects, then disconnects, and retries again, so DHCP is not working. I can assign a IP manually. What to assign as IP, gateway? Just copy/paste the computer configuration, with the same IP? Or increment by 1? or a different subnet entirely?

Comment: Have a look at the update main post